# UIViewController and UITableViewController, how to change self.view then back again?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I dont want to add a sub view, but instead change the "self.view" to another view eg (A warning view) then after the user suppresses the warning I would like to switch back. When ever i try to switch back to the original view i just get a blank screen for reasons i cant understand.

Here is what i currently have in one of my UITableViewControllers

```
//Show warning view controller
self.warningViewControler = [[[WarningViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.view = self.warningViewController.view;


//Then later
self.view = self.tableView; //<< Dosnt work
```

Comment: What does "Dosnt work" mean? Does it give you an error or does it not produce the results you expect? Also, isn't this method kind of shady? Does tableView get released and dealloced when you reassign self.view? Why not just use a UIAlertView if you're displaying a warning?

Comment: @pixelchild is there a reason you don't just present the WarningViewController modally over the current view controller? That would be the simple/consistent way to do this.

Comment: You're doing it wrong, this is not how the iOS view architecture supposed to work, and you will be facing an uphill battle all the way. You need to either embed it as a subview, or create a new view *and* a new view controller, then present that to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your view, and if the original view is defined/linked into XCode, you must retain it before changing self.view to another view. If not, the original view is released and using it back can cause bad things to happen.

Warning :

```
self.warningViewControler = [[[WarningViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.view = self.warningViewController.view
```

is a bad bad call. Because you autorelease the controller but you use its view. So you get a view retained with a released controller after some time. Retain the controller and release it yourself when its view is not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I really did have a feeling it was bad practice. The reason I wasnt using a modal view was because I wanted to keep the navigation bar and tab bar in view. Yet not insert it as a sub view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the better way to do what I think you're trying to do:

```
WarningViewController *warningViewController = [[WarningViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"theRightNiborNil" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:warningViewController animated:YES];

// or if you don't need to support iOS4 any more:

[self presentViewController:warningViewController animated:YES completion:nil]

// and if you aren't using ARC yet, then [warningViewController release];
```

Then in your WarningViewController you want some action that calls:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// or again if this is iOS5..

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope that helps.